# $\|h(x)-h(y)\|\geq 3\|x-y\|$ prove that image of open is open

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $h:\mathbb{R^2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R^2}$ be a surjective map such that

$\|h(x)-h(y)\|\geq 3\|x-y\|$ for all $ x,y\in \mathbb{R^2}$. Here $\|\cdot\|$ denotes euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R^2}$.  Prove that the image of every open set (in $\mathbb{R^2}$) under $h$ is an open set.

My try : Every open set in $\mathbb{R^2}$ can be written as union of balls $B_r(a)$ of radius $r$ entered at $a$ and every ball $B_r(a)$ can be obtained by  scaling up and translating the center of the unit ball $B_1(0)$ in $\mathbb{R^2}$ .So it is enough to prove that $h(B_1(0))$ is open set . So i have to show that for any $(a,b)\in \mathbb{R^2}$ there exists an open ball $B_r(h(a,b)) $ such that $B_r(h(a,b)) \subset h(B_1(0))$ .

My problem is that i can't find an appropriate $r$ .

Please help from here. If the above  approach is completely wrong then provide a solution. Thank you

Comment: Well, first of all, you can't have *any* $(a,b)\in\Bbb R^2$.  Draw some pictures. Try something like $r=\big(1-\|(a,b)\|\big)$. Probably $3r$ would work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note that $h$ is injective (if $h(x)=h(y)$, then $x=y$) hence there is
an inverse $g$ and
$\|g(x)-g(y)\| \le {1 \over 3} \|x-y\|$, so $g$ is continuous.

In particular, if $U$ is open, then $g^{-1}(U) = h(U)$ is open.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter $h$ is explicitly assumed surjective in the question.